# pagedown html resume with aside on first page only

Tags: r, r-markdown, pagedown

I'm attempting to make a CV using R Markdown and the [{pagedown}](https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown) package.

Is it possible to only include the grey aside bar on the first page?

I've tried playing with the page identifiers as described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/#first-pseudo).

```css
@page :first {
  .aside{
    width: var(--sidebar-width);
    padding: 0.6in var(--sidebar-horizontal-padding);
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

My hope was that defining the `.aside` inside `:first` would make the grey aside bar only appear on page one, but no luck. Any suggestions?

A minimal example is  here: https://github.com/wjakethompson/cv-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question got solved [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/pagedown-html-resume-with-aside-on-first-page-only/46351/2).

This can be achieved by adding the following to the css file:

```css
.pagedjs_page:not(:first-of-type) {
  --sidebar-width: 0rem;
  --sidebar-background-color: #ffffff;
  --main-width: calc(var(--content-width) - var(--sidebar-width));
  --decorator-horizontal-margin: 0.2in;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

with an new package updates, this previous answer wont work, you need to add this code chunk inside the rmd section:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
.pagedjs_page:not(:first-of-type) {
  --sidebar-width: 0rem;
  --sidebar-background-color: #ffffff;
  --main-width: calc(var(--content-width) - var(--sidebar-width));
  --decorator-horizontal-margin: 0.2in;
}
```
````